# FancyBOX 2 - How to pass SWF parameters as it used to be in v1.3.4

Tags: jquery, fancybox

How can I use SWF parameters in FancyBox version 2.0.5 (as it used to work in version 1.3.4)

> 'swf' :
>   {
>        'wmode' : 'transparent',
>        'allowfullscreen' : 'true'
>   }

This method seems not to work in the newest version v2.0.5. Has anyone got any solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a html like:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="myobject.swf">open swf</a>
```

pass some parameters using the template (`tpl`) option like

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
 width: 640, // or whatever
 height: 320,
 type: "swf",
 tpl: {
  swf: '<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="100%" height="100%"><param name="wmode" value="transparent" /><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" /><param name="movie" value="'+this.href+'" /><embed src="'+this.href+'" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" width="100%" height="100%" wmode="transparent"></embed></object>',
 }
});
```

Optionally try to pass the parameters within the link itself (and don't use the `tpl` option) like

```
<a class="fancybox" href="myobject.swf?wmode=opaque">open swf</a>
```

Comment: I can't use the tpl option as I have about 30 different swfs. I need to pass the parameters for each swf through the link itself. I tried the following but it's not picking up the height and width, any suggestions?

`<a class="fancybox" href="myobject.swf?width=300&height=250">open swf</a>`

Comment: @AgentZebra : have you try `data-fancybox-width` and `data-fancybox-height` attributes in your link?

Comment: Yes I tried that, it's not working for me. It's not still sizing correctly. I think I should post this as another question.